# Is it possible to connect to Internet-Facing ALB via EndPoints(PrivateLink)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, endpoint

Is it possible to connect to Internet-Facing ALB via EndPoints(PrivateLink) as below?

`VPC-1(EC2) -> EndPoint(PrivateLink) -> VPC-2(ALB)`

`VPC-1: account-1`
`VPC-2: account-2`

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the **direct** pathway of `EC2->PrivateLink->ALB` is **not possible**. The reasons are following:

- PrivateLink requires **Network Load balancer**.
- Thus you have to **link NLB to ALB**. This is doable and explain in the following [AWS blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/using-static-ip-addresses-for-application-load-balancers/). Its still not an easy task and requires some exercise and **internal ALB**.
- To register ALB with NLB you need to use **IP address(es) of ALB nodes**. The problem is that internet-facing ALB exposes public DNS and **public IPs**. [NLB does NOT support public IPs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/load-balancer-target-groups.html#target-type). Subsequently, you can't link NLB with public ALB.

Maybe through some **proxy ec2 instance** you could achieve that. In that way, you could maybe link NLB with private instance which would then  proxy all requests to your public ALB using NAT gateway. In this scenerio you would have: `EC2->PrivateLink->ProxyEC2->NAT->ALB`.

But in my view the effort of setting all this up and maintaining it is not warranted. If your ALB is public anyway, connections to it will go through internet anyway.